# Extract string from Categorical Variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab categorical variable T where referencing T(1) gets me a 1x1 categorical type with string 'Test' in it.

How would I convert this categorical variable directly back to a string so that I may use it in another function that takes a string as an input?

Comment: what do you call a _categorical_ variable ? ... and if you type it in the console what does `whos T` return ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `char` function which as per the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) is used for:

> char: Convert to character array (string)

Example:

```
char(T(1))
```